# How do I sanitize URL endings provided by the user?

Tags: java, http, https

I have some Java code that basically looks like this.

```
final var productName = getUserInput();
System.out.println(makeGetRequest("https://www.myshop.com/products/byName/" + productName));
```

I realise that this is a potential security problem if the user is malicious or could lead to an exception being thrown if the user input is an invalid http query. How do I make sure that the user input really is a product name and nothing else?

Comment: It probably depends on what you want to do with `productName` values. For example, if you build a SQL query to select product(s) from a DB, then use a [prepared statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) to prevent SQL injection attacks. And if the query returns no records, that's a HTTP 404 "not found" response - not necessarily an exception. But like I say, it depends... Not enough info in the question to say much more than that, I think.

Comment: Usually you will urlencode parts of the URL to escape any "dangerous" characters